# getNamespace returns double slash

Tags: ros, roslaunch, namespace, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everybody,
I am experiencing a weird error. Considering a launch file where I launch a node in either of the two following ways

```
<node name="velocity_control" pkg="uav_velocity_control" type="ControlNode"  ns="vtol" output="screen"/>
```

or

```
  <group ns="vtol">
    <node name="velocity_control" pkg="uav_velocity_control" type="ControlNode"  output="screen"/>   
  </group>
```

In my node I have the following line of code

```
ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe(ros::this_node::getNamespace() + "/attitude", queue_size, callbackAngularVelocities);
```

However if I print the obtained topic name

```
std::cout << ros::this_node::getNamespace() << "/attitude" << std::endl;
```

I obtain

> ```
> //vtol/attitude
> ```

I cannot understand this behaviour. I temporarily solved hardcoding the namespace in the node, but I believe you understand the importance of setting the namespaces in the launch file.

Thank you very much

Andrea

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/210322/getnamespace-returns-double-slash/) by [Mago Nick](https://answers.ros.org/users/5206/mago-nick/) on ROS Answers with karma: 385 on 2015-06-01

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [debonair](https://answers.ros.org/users/37218/debonair/) on 2018-10-19**:
can you please answer :https://answers.ros.org/question/306197/getnamespace-returns-incorrect-namespace/

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-10-19**:
@debonair: that is not how this works.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2021-06-11**:
The issue in OP, which is a duplicate slash, same as what https://answers.ros.org/question/306197/getnamespace-returns-incorrect-namespace/ is asking, seems to be a bug. I posted some info in the same link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should use a nodehandle with a relative namespace instead.
The node's namespace includes the full path of the node, including the root. However, your nodehandle is probably the default, which is relative to the node. In this case, it's `/` . Creating a new nodehandle with the node's private namespace, `~`  should fix your error.

Try this:

```
ros::NodeHandle private_n("~");
ros::Subscriber sub = private_n.subscribe("attitude", queue_size, callbackAngularVelocities);
```

EDIT for further reading:

http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/NodeHandles

http://wiki.ros.org/Names

---

Originally posted by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) with karma: 3562 on 2015-06-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mago Nick](https://answers.ros.org/users/5206/mago-nick/) on 2015-06-01**:
That actually solved the issue. Thank you!!!